# Чем опасна слепая инициализация?

Tags: java, инициализация

Прошу объяснить, чем опасна "слепая инициализация" на каком-нибудь примере из практики?

```
public class ShopActivity {
    private int revenue = Prefs.getRevenue();
}
```

Всегда ли нужно выносить код инициализации переменных в конструкторе? Когда можно сделать исключение?

Comment: с чего ты взял, что она опасна?

Comment: @Grundy, частенько в нашем сообществе мой код из вопроса комментировали. Кто-то писал, помню, `не инициализируй переменные вслепую` или там, `перенеси это в конструктор, я тогда игнорировал, а сейчас задумался, какие от неё могут быть проблемы

Comment: _"в конструктор класса/метод `onCreate`"_ - так ведь конструктор и `onCreate` - это сильно разные вещи.

Comment: @Regent, onCreate вроде особо к java не относится?

Comment: Если речь про андроид, то там очень многое завязано на контекст, который гарантированно будет подготовлен как раз к вызову метода `onCreate`

Comment: @Regent, спасибо, поправил

Comment: @Grundy вот то-то и оно, что `onCreate` - специфичная для Android штука, и не очень понятно: автор то ли про "[инлайновая инициализация vs конструктор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916735/default-constructor-vs-inline-field-initialization)", то ли про "инициализация при создании объекта vs инициализация в init-методе"

Comment: @Flippy то есть вас всё-таки интересует вопрос в разрезе init-метода?

Comment: @Regent, да, только в нем, метку андроида я же не указал. А `onCreate` по привычке

Comment: @Flippy при создании объекта вы опираетесь на какие-то данные извне. Те данные, что точно готовы к моменту вызова конструктора, можно спокойно использовать сразу (в конструкторе / inline). Те данные, что будут готовы позже, передаются в init-метод, который вызывается в соответствующий момент. Вот как бы и всё. Ну и init-метод иногда удобнее при внедрении зависимостей.

Comment: @Flippy правда, учитывая что вы опять отредактировали вопрос, и с init-метода переехали на конструктор (что кардинально меняет суть вопроса), то, видимо, зря я тут распинался сейчас.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Компилятор переносит инициализацию полей в месте объявления (как и инициализацию полей в нестатических блоках) в конструктор (точнее говоря, во все имеющиеся).

Инициализация полей при объявлении и инициализация полей в конструкторе – это *практически* одно и то же. Разница лишь в том, что:

1. Инициализация полей в месте объявления происходит перед инициализацией полей в конструкторе.
2. В случае инициализации полей в месте объявления невозможно перехватить исключение (при этом, если исключение checked, то нужно будет создать конструктор, который далее будет прокидывать возникшее исключение).

Comment: А я вот не помню - вроде еще если в процессе инициализации полей вы выделите где-то non-heap память, а потом у вас случится эксепшен, то ваш finalize не отработает.

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем теоретически, то инициализируя свойства класса в момент их объявления необходимо быть твердо уверенным в том, что используемые для инициализации объекты существуют, а методы отработают корректно, так как вставить проверки и `try/catch` не получится.

```
public class Test{
    private Int number = 10;    
//тут вообще никаких проблем
    private String string = SomeStaticClass.getString(); 
//А если getString() бросит исключение?
    private Int number2 = Integer.parseInt(string); 
//А если string "кривая"?
    private View view = findViewById(R.id.view); 
//findViewById работает с инициализированным контекстом, которого на данном моменте просто не существует
}
```